# Python, Pandas: Use the GroupBy.groups description to apply it to another grouping

Tags: python, pandas

Let's consider a DataFrame that contains 1 row of 2 values per each day of the month of Jan 2010:

```
date_range = pd.date_range(dt(2010,1,1), dt(2010,1,31), freq='1D')
df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.rand(len(date_range),2), index = date_range)
```

I split that DataFrame into a list of 5 DataFrames, each of them containing 1 week worth of data from the original: `df_weeks = [g for n, g in df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('W'))]`

If I type `df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('W')).groups` I can see a dict explaining how the groups are split:

```
{Timestamp('2010-01-03 00:00:00', freq='W-SUN'): 3,
 Timestamp('2010-01-10 00:00:00', freq='W-SUN'): 10,
 Timestamp('2010-01-17 00:00:00', freq='W-SUN'): 17,
 Timestamp('2010-01-24 00:00:00', freq='W-SUN'): 24,
 Timestamp('2010-01-31 00:00:00', freq='W-SUN'): 31}
```

Let's consider another TimeSerie that has sparser data yet overlaps with the first one:

```
observations = pd.DataFrame(data =np.random.rand(5,2), index = (dt(2010,1,12), dt(2010,1,18), dt(2010,1,20), dt(2010,1,22), dt(2010,1,28)))
```

If I run the same code `obs_weeks = [g for n, g in observations.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('W'))]`, obviously it will returns less DataFrames in the list, as the data covers less span. `observations.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('W')).groups` returns :

```
{Timestamp('2010-01-17 00:00:00', freq='W-SUN'): 1,
 Timestamp('2010-01-24 00:00:00', freq='W-SUN'): 4,
 Timestamp('2010-01-31 00:00:00', freq='W-SUN'): 5}
```

But would there be a way to **reuse the groups of the first DataFrame.GroupBy** to apply it to the second one? i.e. that would mean in that specific case ending up with a variable `obs_weeks` containing 5 DataFrames spanning the same time range as `df_weeks` , 2 of them being empty ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution to your problem would be to make sure the observations dataframe contains all the dates that the df dataframe does. You can do this with the `reindex` method. You will then have the exact same groups. You can also use `resample('W')` instead of `groupby(pd.Timegrouper('W'))`

```
obs2 = observations.reindex(df.index)

obs2.resample('W').groups

{Timestamp('2010-01-03 00:00:00', freq='W-SUN'): 3,
 Timestamp('2010-01-10 00:00:00', freq='W-SUN'): 10,
 Timestamp('2010-01-17 00:00:00', freq='W-SUN'): 17,
 Timestamp('2010-01-24 00:00:00', freq='W-SUN'): 24,
 Timestamp('2010-01-31 00:00:00', freq='W-SUN'): 31}
```

And if we do a simple aggregation like sum we can see the results of both frames

```
df.resample('W').sum()

                 0         1
2010-01-03  1.990558  2.555191
2010-01-10  2.707777  3.771756
2010-01-17  2.799897  3.353363
2010-01-24  3.165479  2.778870
2010-01-31  4.946577  3.394211
```

And now with `obs2` which has 2 missing groups

```
obs2.resample('W').sum()

                   0         1
2010-01-03       NaN       NaN
2010-01-10       NaN       NaN
2010-01-17  0.172341  0.137136
2010-01-24  1.752472  2.375306
2010-01-31  0.711525  0.124271
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However I am receiving the following error message when trying `observations.reindex(df)` : `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: I am using a slightly different dataset for `observations` with dates 18/01, 20/01, 22/01, 28/01, but I would assume this should still work.