# Python, Pandas: Reindex/Slice DataFrame with duplicate Index values

Tags: python, pandas

Let's consider a DataFrame that contains 1 row of 2 values per each day of the month of Jan 2010:

```
date_range = pd.date_range(dt(2010,1,1), dt(2010,1,31), freq='1D')
df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.rand(len(date_range),2), index = date_range)
```

and another timeserie with sparser data and duplicate index values:

```
observations = pd.DataFrame(data =np.random.rand(7,2), index = (dt(2010,1,12),
dt(2010,1,18), dt(2010,1,20), dt(2010,1,20), dt(2010,1,22), dt(2010,1,22),dt(2010,1,28)))
```

I split the first DataFrame `df` into a list of 5 DataFrames, each of them containing 1 week worth of data from the original: `df_weeks = [g for n, g in df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('W'))]`

Now I would like to split the data of the second DataFrame by the same 5 weeks.  i.e. that would mean in that specific case ending up with a variable obs_weeks containing 5 DataFrames spanning the same time range as df_weeks , 2 of them being empty.

I tried using `reindex` such as in this question: [Python, Pandas: Use the GroupBy.groups description to apply it to another grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41669000/python-pandas-use-the-groupby-groups-description-to-apply-it-to-another-groupi)

and Periods:

```
p1 =[x.to_period() for x in list(df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('W')).groups.keys())]
p1 = sorted(p1)
dfs=[]
for p in p1:
    dff = observations.truncate(p.start_time, p.end_time)
    dfs.append(dff)
```

(see this question: [Python, Pandas: Boolean Indexing Comparing DateTimeIndex to Period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676020/python-pandas-boolean-indexing-comparing-datetimeindex-to-period))

The problem is that if some values in the index of `observations` are duplicates (and this is the case) none of those method functions. i also tried to change the index of `observations` to a normal column and do the slicing on that column, but i received error message as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by doing a simple filter:

```
p1 = [x.to_period() for x in list(df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('W')).groups.keys())]
p1 = sorted(p1)
dfs = []
for p in p1:
    dff = observations.ix[
        (observations.index >= p.start_time) &
        (observations.index < p.end_time)]
    dfs.append(dff)
```